# Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found ,and i have tensorflow.version==2.6.0

Tags: python, tensorflow

I downloaded TensorFlow versions 2.1.0 and cudnn 10.1.
However, there was the following error:

> "Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; drror:
> cudart64_110.dll not found'

So, I checked the TensorFlow version on the conda list, which says 2.1.0 and when the TensorFlow on the photo appears on python, it is 2.6 when it is checked.

**Screenshot of the error:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the error screenshot, it shows you have installed `Tensorflow==2.6.0`.
You need to install `TF 2.6` compatible `CUDA 11.2` and `cuDNN 8.1`.

Check this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu) to know about build configuration details.

OR

You can surpass this warning using below code:

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
```